# How to get matched rows and insert into multiple tables in SQL

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have 4 tables:

table1

```
ID   PNTID col3 col4 col5
123  456   y    y    0
444  456   y    y    0
900  878   n    n    1
```

table 2

```
ID    TID col3   col4 col5 col6
123   999   777    888    0   x
456   111   988    -    -   -
444   123   988    -    -   -
```

table 2- after update

```
ID    TID col3   col4 col5 col6
123   111   777    888    0   x
456   111   988    -    -   -
444   111   988    -    -   -
```

table 3 -update or insert

```
TID col2 col3 col4 col5
111  988   x   x    x
```

table 4 -update or insert

```
TID col2 col3 col4 col5
111  988 x   x    x
```

I am trying to achieve:

-> Check the col3,col4,col5 if there values matching like Y,Y and 0 then get the values of ID  from table 2 that matches PNTID of table1 such as TID , col3..

->Update table 2 wherein ID has same PNTID table1 such as ID : 123, 444

->In table 3,Check TID is there or not if its there then update col2 with the value of table2.col3 of PNTID(ID- col in table 2) else insert a new row as columns in table 2(TID,col,col2,col3...)

Similarly , Need to update or insert table 4 with respect to table 2.

I am trying to build the subqueries .like to get the matched rows of table 1 and 2 the proceed further.

```
SELECT * 
FROM   dbo.table tb1 
       INNER JOIN table2 tb2  
               ON tb1.ID = tb2.ID 
WHERE  tb1.col3 = 'Y' 
AND    tb1.col4 = 'Y' 
AND    tb1.col5 = 0
```

this gives me matched rows but how to fetch values and insert into other tables record by record as table 1 and 2 have many records.
can anyone help me on this?

Thanks!

Comment: Try creating a [sqlFiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/)

Comment: Are you using MySQL or MS SQL Server?

Comment: please make sure your description matches with your table sample. You mention `PNTID` of table2, but that column does not appear in your sample for table 2

Comment: @jarlh MS SQL Server.

Comment: @Squirrel ..my bad.just updated the  description.

Comment: I don't get this at all. I understand that table 1 444  456   y    y    0 is of interest and that you want to pick up table 2 tid 111 but I don't see the logic for updating table 2 rows 1 and three to 111 and why col3 in row 3 changes to 987. ALSO although you can update multiple tables in a query you cannot insert to multiple tables in a query and I don't get what event would trigger all these updates/inserts - or whether this would be a periodic event run by a procedure call.

Comment: @P.Salmon .yes it will be a periodic event run by a proc.sorry col3 is 988.I am trying to store the matched result of table1 and table2 into temp table and then update into multiple tables

Comment: please elaborate more on the logic and be more precise which table are you referring to. Like `Check the col3,col4,col5 if there values matching like Y,Y and 0 then get the values of ID from table 2 that matches PNTID of table1 such as TID , col3.` . `col3,col4,col5` is from which table ? You are matching table2 ID to table1 PNTID ? or TID or ID ? Please understand that we have no idea of your database schema and what you are trying to achieve, you need to help us to understand in order for us to help you

Comment: @squirrel... condition check should be done on table 1 wherein we get the Validated rows from table 1 .PNTID of table 1 is the ID of table 2 ,yes I am matching table 2 ID to table 1 PNTID.

Answer (score 0):

```
UPDATE <table to update t1>INNER JOIN <table with inner join t2>
ON t1 = t2
SET t1.id =t2.id
WHERE <condition>
```

the above code is for updation on fly

if this does not work try using triggers